# Office add-in manifest does not work when adding appdomains tag

Tags: office365, office-addins

I'm working on a 'new style' Office add-in based on html+js. When I add an appdomains tag as per https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/appdomains to be able to open an external pop-up within the add-in frame itself, the add-in stops working altogether. The manifest seems valid and there is nothing else I've changed other than the appdomains tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the manifest is somehow read line-by-line and therefore the sequence in which the different xml elements are presented matters.

I'm not sure what your manifest looks like but you should probably move appdomain up or down depending on where it is now. It should be right after the description XML element.